# Vue.js 3, vue-router, @click event reloads whole page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Im new to Vue and i want while on mobile navigation when I click menuItem I run function toggleMenu(open/close Menu), but then whole page reload, who to prevent that?
This is my link:

```
 <router-link to="/" @click="toggleMenu">
    <div class="nav-item">Home</div>
  </router-link>
```

I tried adding @click.prevent and it prevents reload but not sending me to path.

**EDIT:**

So i make it works thanks to Boussadjra Brahim answer, but I did it with CompositionAPI and i used `useRouter()` hook from `vue-router`

Template:

```
 <router-link
  to="/"
  @click.prevent="toggleMenu">
  Home </router-link>
```

setup():

```
const router = useRouter();

function toggleMenu(){
   router.push('/'); 
}
```

Comment: Please create a Codesandbox or replicate your error in some other platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `prevent` modifier as you did then inside the `toggleMenu` add `this.$router.push("/");` :

```
 <router-link to="/" @click.prevent="toggleMenu">
    <div class="nav-item">Home</div>
  </router-link>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dubinsky-9vejt?file=/src/App.vue:467-490)